# reactJS state array of objects - how do I reference the state array object in setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following declaration:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        productArray: [{
            barcode: '',
            name: ''
        }],
        numberOfRecords: '',
        return_code: '',
        return_string: ''
    };        
}
```

My hope is to reference the state fields like this:

> this.state.productArray[0].barcode and this.state.productArray[1]

I also have a piece of code where I try to update the state.  The code looks like this:

```
for (counter=0;counter<numberOfRecords;counter++) {

    currentComponent.setState({productArray[counter].barcode: tempData.barcode[counter]});                        
    currentComponent.setState({productArray[counter].name: tempData.name[counter]});
}
```

This does not compile and the error is pointing to the first setState command.  The compiler is pointing at the [ in the reference to productArray[counter].barcode saying it expected a ','.

Am I defining the state correctly?  If not, what would the proper syntax be?  If yes, what is proper syntax to reference the individual state field pieces?

Comment: why is `numberOfRecords` an empty string and not a number? and how about just setting `currentComponent.setState({ productArray: tempData })`?

Comment: my bad on the default value of numberOfRecords.  I should initialize it to zero.  As for the data, I am picking off specific pieces of the tempData array so I did not feel it was necessary to save all the tempData data in the state.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, this wasn't apparent to me. Is `numberOfRecords` really state, or can it be easily computed? Like `tempData.length` for example?

Comment: excellent point.  I can remove numberOfRecords from state and get it from tempData.length.

Comment: So far the great question of the day, keep learning. I have given without making shallow copies yourself and you can utilize the power of JS.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you only need a single call to `setState` something you can do is create a temporary variable where to store the computation such as

```
const { productArray, numberOfRecords } = this.state;
const newProducts = [ ... productArray ];
for( let counter = 0; counter < numberOfRecords; counter ) {
    const item = newProducts[ counter];
    newProducts[ counter] = { ...item, barcode: 'value' }, 
}

this.setState({ productArray: newProducts });
```

By using the spread operator `...` you can create [shallow copies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy) of objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

you can't directly immutate the state please do it as

```
let tempvar = this.state.productArray;
for (counter=0;counter<numberOfRecords;counter++) {
tempvar[counter].barcode= newValue
}
this.setState({productArray:tempvar})
```

Comment: If that is the case, how would I be able to pass the state.productArray in an arrow function/map so I can render the data in state.productArray dynamically?

Comment: you can render it normally as you are not modifying the state their

Comment: you can do as this.state.productArray.map(index=><div>index.barcode</div>)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to updated nested array of objects is to utilize the power of `Object.assign`. Keep in mind, that Object.assign will not perform a deep cloning, since it only copies property values,

```
this.setState({
    productArray:  Object.assign({}, this.state.productArray[0], {
      barcode: 'any value',
    })}, ()=>{
      console.log(this.state)
    }
  );
```

In your case, that's how you can achieve this with shorthand notation:

```
 for (var counter = 0; counter < 1; counter++) {
  this.setState({
    productArray:  Object.assign({}, this.state.productArray[counter], {
      barcode: tempData.barcode[counter],
      name: tempData.name[counter]
    })}, ()=>{
      console.log(this.state)
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> As for the data, I am picking off specific pieces of the tempData array

and

> I can remove numberOfRecords from state and get it from tempData.length.

Ok, so `productArray` contains a subset of properties of the objects from `tempData`, and not a subset of items.

Then I'd not even bother trying to copy the values over and simply [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the new values.

```
currentComponent.setState({ 
  productArray: tempData.map(item => {
    const {barcode, name} = item;
    return {barcode, name};
  })
});

//or in short

currentComponent.setState({ 
  productArray: tempData.map(({barcode, name}) => ({barcode, name}))
});
```

To answer your question; If you want to access and update some nested property, you should go with a update-function in `setState()` so ALL previous updates have been applied to `this.state` BEFORE your code tries to modify it.

Something like this:

```
currentComponent.setState((state) => {
  for(let i = 0; i<tempData.length; ++i){
    let from = tempData[i], to = state.productArray[i];

    to.name = from.name;
    to.barcode = from.barcode;
  }
  return state;
});
```

The downside/flaw of this approach is, that doesn't deal with the situations where `tempData.length !== state.productArray.length`.

Comment: Since I'm placing this code in componentWillMount() and I dont update the state anywhere else in the process, I dont think I need to worry about that instance.